# disable terminal bell except when called manually

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux, bell

The terminal bell rings in several scenarios.  To name a few:

1. when you attempt to delete when at the beginning of a prompt
2. when you attempt to tab complete with no valid options
3. in vim, when you attempt to move the cursor when i cannot move (i.e. move down while on the last line)

And there's plenty others.  What I want to do is make is to the only time the bell will ring is when I deliberately make it ring, such as with `echo -e "\a"`.

I've added `set bell-style none` to my `.inputrc`, but it still rings in vim, and if I start tmux, I get the first 2 bells above as well.  I it possible to tell bash never to ring the bell unless I deliberately tell it to?